# copying the text from text box(GUI) into a file

Tags: python, tkinter

i have build a GUI in which if the buttons are pressed the output of the functions come into the text box. now i want to create a report by writing the contents to a text file.

the contents of the text box are:

```
Checks       Status          Remarks

ECHConnect   checked         Structure disintegrates

ECHQUALITY   checked         All 171665 elements are suitable


ECHPenetra   checked         EChPenet: 26093 elements penetrate/touch each other

ECHCha       not checked     

ECHCoincid   checked         20 coincident elements

ECHEdgeLen   checked         Shortest edge length = 0.2669
```

is there any command to do it?

the code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import Tkinter as tk
from tkFileDialog   import *
import re

class StageGui:
    prot=0
    log=0
    def __init__(self,parent,tex):
        self.tex=tex
        self.f = tk.Frame(main, width=500, height=500)
        self.b1=tk.Button(main,text='Import prot file',command=self.callback).pack(side='left',anchor='nw')
        self.b2=tk.Button(main,text='Import log file',command=self.callback1).pack(side='left',anchor='nw')
        self.xf = tk.Frame(self.f,relief='groove', borderwidth=2)
        self.button=tk.Button(self.xf, text="CHECK",command=self.check).pack(side='left', padx=5,pady=8)
        self.button2=tk.Button(self.xf, text="SUMMARY",command=summary).pack(side='left', padx=5,pady=8)
        self.button3=tk.Button(self.xf, text="INERTIA",command=inertia).pack(side='left', padx=5,pady=8)
        self.button1=tk.Button(self.xf, text="CREATE REPORT").pack(side='left', padx=5,pady=8)
        self.xf.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.35, anchor='nw')
        self.label1=tk.Label(self.f, text='standard checks').place(relx=.06, rely=0.35,anchor='w')
        self.f.pack(side='left',fill='y',expand=1)

    def callback(self):
        name= askopenfilename()
        StageGui.prot=name
        self.printstatements(StageGui.prot)
    def printstatements(self,name):
        self.tex.insert('end','\nthe file has been imported \n')
        s='the path of the imported file is {}\n'.format(name)
        self.tex.insert('end',s)
        self.tex.see(tk.END)
        return
    def callback1(self):
        name1= askopenfilename()
        StageGui.log=name1
        self.printstatements(StageGui.log)
    def check(self):
        file=open(StageGui.prot,'r')
        a,b,c='Checks','Status','Remarks'
        mess='\n{0:10s} \t {1:10s} \t {2:100s}\n'.format(a,b,c)
        self.tex.insert('end',mess)
        count_string_occurance(file)

def count_string_occurance(file):
    string = "test"
    f = file
    contents = f.read()
    commcheck=['ECHConnect','ECHQUALITY','ECHPenetra','ECHCha','ECHCoincid','ECHEdgeLen','EMSameNorm','EEBeam','NEQ','Outline','NCHeck_nodes','GDelete']
    remcheck=['Label','INERTIA','Summary']
    special=['ECht']
    s='ECht'
    num=[]
    rnum=[]
    snum=[]
    for i in range(len(commcheck)):
        string=commcheck[i]
        num.append(contents.count(string))
    s=['connected','elements are suitable','penetrations','minimum','coincident elements','Shortest','to be reoriented','modified according to','multiple nodes found','Free edges displayed in','nodes are displayed','missing']
    p=['disintegrates','failed','touch','maximum','no coincident elements','Longest','reoriented','linked','multiple nodes found','free','nodes are displayed','elements deleted']
    for i in range(len(num)):
        if num[i]>0:
            status='checked'
            with open(StageGui.log,'r') as fy:
                for line in fy:
                    if s[i] in line:
                        mess='\n{0:10s} \t {1:10s} \t {2:100s}\n'.format(commcheck[i],status,line)
                        tex.insert('end',mess)
                        break
                    elif p[i] in line:
                        mess= '\n{0:10s} \t {1:10s} \t {2:100s}\n'.format(commcheck[i],status,line)
                        tex.insert('end',mess)
        else:
            status='not checked'
            new= '\n{0:10s} \t {1:10s} \t \n'.format(commcheck[i],status)
            tex.insert('end',new)
    for i in range(len(remcheck)):
        nstring=remcheck[i]
        rnum.append(contents.count(nstring))
    for i in range(len(rnum)):
        if rnum[i]>0:
            status='checked'
            mess='\n{0:10s} \t {1:10s} \t \n'.format(remcheck[i],status)
            tex.insert('end',mess)
        else:
            status='not checked'
            new= '\n{0:10s} \t {1:10s} \t \n'.format(remcheck[i],status)
            tex.insert('end',new)

    nstring1=special[0]
    flag=0
    if nstring1=='ECht':
        searchstring='degenerated'
        with open(StageGui.log,'r') as fz:
            for line in fz:
                if searchstring in line:
                    status='checked'
                    mess='\n{0:10s} \t {1:10s} \t {2:100s}\n'.format(nstring1,status,line)
                    tex.insert('end',mess)
                    flag=1
                    break
            if flag==0:
                status2='not checked'
                mess2='\n{0:10s} \t {1:10s} \t \n'.format(nstring1,status2)
                tex.insert('end',mess2)
    f.close()

def summary():
    tex.delete('1.0','end')
    with open(StageGui.prot,'r') as input:
        intable = False
        for line in input:
                if line.strip() == "Summary":
                intable = True
                if line.strip() == "*  ============================== INERTIA ==============================":
                        intable = False
                if intable and line.strip().startswith("*"):
                        z=(line.strip())
                tex.insert('end','\n')
                tex.insert('end',z)
                tex.insert('end','\n')

def inertia():
    tex.delete('1.0','end')
    with open(StageGui.prot,'r') as input:
        intable = False
        for line in input:
                if line.strip() == "*  ============================== INERTIA ==============================":
                        intable = True
            if line.strip() == "Summary":
                intable = False
                if intable and line.strip().startswith("*"):
                        z=(line.strip())
                tex.insert('end','\n')
                tex.insert('end',z)
                tex.insert('end','\n')




main = tk.Tk()
tex= tk.Text(main,width=100)
tex.pack(side='bottom',anchor='s',fill='both',expand='yes')
stagegui=StageGui(main,tex)
main.title('prototype')
main.geometry('800x800+300+300')
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the code you have so far.

Comment: i've updated the post with the code. can you just check it @WilliamMcBrine

Comment: Your indentation is messed up, please fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically there are two approaches you could take: The first, which I'd normally prefer, would be to keep track of the values you're writing to the window, and write them separately to the file in the same way. But, if you really want to read from the window, it's simple:

```
outtext = tex.get('1.0', 'end')
outfile = open('whatever', 'w')
outfile.write(outtext)
outfile.close()
```

Comment: sorry for the wrong indentation, but the code lines which you gave works thank you very much.......